# Getting NodeValue xml parsing Android

Tags: android, parsing

My Xml result looks like:

```
<search_results count="451">
<query>
 hello
</query>
<clinical_study>
<order>1</order>
<score>0.92784</score>
<nct_id>NCT01032902</nct_id>
</clinical_study>
```

I want to get that count tag value i.e., 451 in this case.

Am using following code:

```
NodeList nodeLst1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("search_results");
           // System.out.println("count.."+doc.getElementsByTagName("search_results").item(0).getUserData("count"));
           // System.out.println("count22.."+doc.getElementsByTagName("query").item(0).getUserData("query"));


            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("query");
            Element fstNmElmnt1 = (Element) nodeLst.item(0);
            NodeList fstNm1 = fstNmElmnt1.getChildNodes();
            nodeValue = ((Node) fstNm1.item(0)).getNodeValue();
            System.out.println("TotalCount: "+nodeValue);
```

Am geting the "query" tag value but am not able to retrieve the count value.
How to get that?? Help..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a function that i made to do that :D

to call do something like `readAtributes(data, "search_results");`

it returns a hash table with every atribute. you can change to return just the value you need.
hope it helps

```
private Hashtable<String, String> readAtributes(Element data, String tag) {
    Hashtable<String, String> dataReaded = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    NodeList nodelist = data.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = nodelist.item(i);
        if (n instanceof Element && n.hasAttributes()) {
            NamedNodeMap attrs = n.getAttributes();
            for (int j = 0; j < attrs.getLength(); j++) {
                Attr attribute = (Attr) attrs.item(j);
                dataReaded.put(attribute.getName(), attribute.getValue());
                System.out.println("" + attribute.getName() + "="
                        + attribute.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return dataReaded;
}
```

Comment: Attributes is the word that am looking for it worked with that..thanx